# How to specify digits and decimal places with NumberFormatInfo

Tags: .net, number-formatting

I need to format a number like "1.2452" to show "452" So I don't want to see all numbers. The thing is, I am not able to control the display number directly, I can only format it by setting a format string of type according to the NumberFormatInfo Class.  Is this possible, and if so how?

cheers

EDIT:

I found out I could subscribe to a "FormatEvent", which enabled me to make custom format as a string after the number formatting. Thanks everybody for the help and insight! :)

Comment: I just don't want to display the full number. Only the last digits matter. It's for forex quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own formatting specifiers by implementing IFormatter.  But you cannot do so for the types that are already baked into .NET.  Like System.Double or System.Decimal, or whatever the type of the variable whose value is 1.2452.  The format specifiers that are baked in for these standard .NET types don't allow picking off the 3 last digits.

A custom culture with an altered NumberFormatInfo doesn't give you enough control over the formatting.

You'll need to get control over the actual value.  Then it is simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's not possible because you can only filter out from least to most significant.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we would need to know exactly what algorithm you need to format the number.
But you could convert it to a string and then just do a substring.

Answer (score 0):

using .net

```
[math]::pi                             *-- give 3.1415926538979*
([math]::pi).tostring().split(".")[1]  *-- gives: 14159265358979*
([math]::pi).tostring().split(".")[1].substring(0,4) *-- Gives : 1415*
```

Comment: Using .NET?  Are you sure about that?!

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormatInfo does not provide enough flexibility to accomodate this (bizarre) format.  I would suggest just having a ReadOnly property that formats your number accordingly...

```
public string NumberFormatted
{
    get
    {
        string num = YourNumber.ToString();
        int index = num.IndexOf(".");
        if(index > -1 && index < num.Length - 2)
            num = num.Substring(index + 2);
        return num;
     }
}
```